# Is samsung 850 Pro 256 GB compatible with Dell Inspiron 15 - 7000?

Tags: laptop, ssd, dell-inspiron

I have a [Dell Inspiron 15 - 7000](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/inspiron-15-7537/pd) and I ordered [Samsung 850 Pro 256GB SSD MZ-7KE256BW](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-7KE256BW) without checking if its compatible or not. Someone just told me that I might have compatibility issues.

Dell says that the notebook has the following Chipset

```
Mobile Intel® HM76 Express Chipset
```

I checked from [Intel's website](http://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/chipsets/performance-chipsets/mobile-chipset-hm76.html) that the Chipset has:

```
Serial ATA (SATA)* 6 Gb/s and 3 Gb/s
```

Now how do I check if the SSD is compatible with my laptop?

Additional Specs:

Intel Core i7, 16 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD(To be replaced with SSD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i,-sata-ii-and-sata-iii

You'll be fine.  You've bought a SATA III Drive - which is also known as SATA 6 Gb/s.. your motherboard supports SATA 6 GB/S (SATA III) - so it will be ok.

Also, it is worth noting that since SATA is backward compatible, you would have been ok either way and if your drive or motherboard were slower, then the parts would still work - but at the slower of the 2 speeds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure that the drive will perform at the advertised speed, if not I'll cancel the order and buy a less expensive ssd.

Comment: SATA will auto-negotiate.  It doesn't matter what the model of drive or motherboard is, the combination will always work at the fastest speed which both devices can handle.  The same is actually true of a lot fo things... USB, Ethernet...anyway, please upvote and/or accept this answer if it helped :)